# Which microcontroller for fast high quality audio switching and playback

Tags: audio, microcontroller

I'm building a device which will play high quality sound samples and will switch between samples in >5ms when a signal is applied.

I'm after a microcontroller which can allow this - I need 4 I/O pins for triggering the transistions between sounds, as well as the output pin(s) for the audio.  The duration of the audio files will be 50ms or so but ideally would have enough storage to allow the files to be 1 second or longer.  It will loop the current file until told to change.  I don't want audiable pops or suchlike when switching files or running other commands - but there shouldn't be a need for anything complex to run beside it, it's purely audio playing and switching.

I've looked at various microcontrollers in the arduino family but they don't seem optimal for this purpose - (tried for example mozzi library for arduino but it's not fantastic quality).  Ideally I could do it all on the chip (whatever it is, doesn't need to be arduino) - without needing external storage or RAM modules.  But if that's neccessary I'll do it.  The solution is to fit in a 2cm wide cylinder (but no length constraints) so would be ideally within that - so no SD card modules or whatever.  Language wise - I'm fairly new to them all - but can learn whatever would be best.

Audio - (44.1kHz CD quality WAV, although could obviously switch to a different format if neccessary).  If this is totally impossible to play such a high quality sound - then sound quality could be less.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a simple application like this you would be best to just use a small ARM Cortex M device hooked up to an external SPI FLASH chip. Most microcontrollers scale processing power and RAM with FLASH storage so keeping it all on one chip will result in a grotesquely over-powered solution. Serial FLASH memory is very cheap, easy to use, and you can change the size in the future if you need to add more samples.

For the audio side if you really want CD quality you'll have to look at getting a external audio DAC as I don't know of any microcontrollers that integrate a CD quality codec. External DACs aren't expensive or complex to use, but just adds to the physical size and BOM cost. Many Cortex chips have built in 12-bit DACs though so if the audio has a reasonably small dynamic range you might find this is suitable for your needs.

In terms of minimising pops and clicks the Cortex devices will have enough power for some basic filtering to deal with this. I would recommend against Arduino though as you will quickly come up against processing power limitations and I doubt you will want to dive into assembler optimisations.